# Elasticsearch 5.0.2 failed to search for keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing a very simple item with a field define as such:

```
"comid": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "store": "false",
  "index": "no",
  "include_in_all": false, 
  "doc_values": false
}
```

I then ingested a single item where comid = "this is an id"
When I query the item with exact match "this is an id"

I got this error:

```
cannot search on field [comid] since it is not indexed
```

Maybe I misunderstood the documentation but I thought we are able to search for keyword (using exact match) ?

I think I could get around this problem by changing the type from keyword to text and then using a keyword analyzer (which is noop if I understood it correctly) but it seems weird to do this for every keyword type field.

I must be missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not indexed, the field data is only stored in the document, not the index so you cannot search using that field.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html

Comment: If I reindex with "index" : true , I could query the field however doesn't this means that the field is now analyzed? so now I need to specify a noop analyzer for each keyword field which i think is weird.  Unless the default analyzer for keyword is keyword analyzer (which is noop)

Comment: Yes, by default it is analyzed. This is a pretty sensible default for a search engine. You can change the default analyzer, though: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html

Comment: it seems that for type "keyword" it will not accept "analyzer" as it will throw error.  The official documentation doesn't mention what the default analyzer for "keyword" type either.  However your original message helped me realized that I was confused between index and analyze, so I am marking it as the answer